# Adding row values dynamically

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, vba

I have a table lets say as shown in pic[image]

I am trying to sum numbers say in row X dynamically. If the users chosses FY11 and FY16 then I have to provide sum of cells from FY11 to FY16.

Any solutions?

Comment: How do you want the user to select the **FYs** ??

Comment: I have provided drop down buttons in two cells. One provides the start and the other the end date

Comment: A pivot table would be great for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data setup looks like this:

[image]

In cell B6 is the drop down for FY Start and in B7 is the drop down for FY End.  The sum of the various rows (X, Y, and Z) for the start - end FY's selected are in cells B9 and down.  The formula in cell B9 and copied down is:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK($B$6:$B$7)>0,"",SUM(INDEX($B2:$H2,MATCH($B$6,$B$1:$H$1,0)):INDEX($B2:$H2,MATCH($B$7,$B$1:$H$1,0))))
```